# Работа с backgroundworker c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, backgroundworker

Всем добрый день! В программе потребовалось реализовать отправку запроса в БД и получение ответа в отдельном потоке, решил обратиться к backgroundworker.
При открытии второй формы в программе и клике на чекбоксе нужно запустить третью форму (с прогрессбаром и таймером) и в воркере получить таблицу из базы, после получения отобразить в датагриде на второй форме и закрыть третью. Написал следующий код, но работает странно - датагрид не обновляется и третья форма не закрывается автоматически. В чем косяк? Также планировал добавить возможность прервать работу воркера из 3 формы по клику на кнопку "Прервать", но пока остановился на этом, через Threads сделать получилось, но хочется более верно реализовать (закомментированные куски кода остались от другой идеи)

```
public partial class Organizations : Form
{
    Progress ThirdForm;
    public Thread potok;
    public Thread potok1;
    public BackgroundWorker BW;

    public Organizations()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork +=
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted +=
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    public delegate void Del();

    DataTable Loading(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bool b2 = false;
        DataTable dt;
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        } 
        else
        { 
            // Получение строки соединения с базой данных и заполнение таблицы на CalculationForm
            var cn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            cn.ConnectionString = ConnString.GetConnectionString();
            cn.Open();
            //  Идентификатор расчета

            if (((Reports)(Application.OpenForms[0])).textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Необходимо сначала выбрать расчет!", "Обработчик кнопки Организации", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return dt = null;
            }
            else
            {
                int IdCostsResultTask = Convert.ToInt32(((Reports)(Application.OpenForms[0])).textBox1.Text);
                string sqlQuery = @" SELECT cr.ExportIdListEdu 'ExportIdListEdu', ReestrEdu.IdListEdu 'IdListEdu',slovar..ListEdu.Name 'ShortName', slovar..ListEdu.LongName 'Name' FROM ReestrEdu " +
                                   " LEFT JOIN slovar..ListEdu on ReestrEdu.IdListEdu = slovar..ListEdu.IdListEdu " +
                                   " LEFT JOIN CostsResult as cr on ReestrEdu.IdListEdu = cr.ExportIdListEdu or ReestrEdu.IdListEdu = cr.IdListEdu" +
                                   " WHERE cr.IdCostsResultTask = " + IdCostsResultTask + " and slovar..ListEdu.LongName is not null " +
                                   " Group By cr.ExportIdListEdu, ReestrEdu.IdListEdu, slovar..ListEdu.Name, slovar..ListEdu.LongName  ORDER BY 1,2 ";
                var myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn);
                myCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                using (myReader)
                {
                    var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    table.Load(myReader);
                    dt = table;
                }
                myReader.Dispose();
                cn.Close();

                b2 = true;
            }
        }
        return dt;   
    }

    DataTable Loading2(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bool b2 = false;
        DataTable dt2;
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        } 
        else
        { 
            // Получение строки соединения с базой данных и заполнение таблицы на CalculationForm
            var cn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            cn.ConnectionString = ConnString.GetConnectionString();
            cn.Open();
            //  Идентификатор расчета
            if (((Reports)(Application.OpenForms[0])).textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Необходимо сначала выбрать расчет!", "Обработчик кнопки Организации", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return dt2 = null;
            }
            else
            {
                int IdCostsResultTask = Convert.ToInt32(((Reports)(Application.OpenForms[0])).textBox1.Text);
                string sqlQuery = @" SELECT cr.ExportIdListEdu 'ExportIdListEdu', ReestrEdu.IdListEdu 'IdListEdu',slovar..ListEdu.Name 'ShortName', slovar..ListEdu.LongName 'Name' FROM ReestrEdu " +
                                   " LEFT JOIN slovar..ListEdu on ReestrEdu.IdListEdu = slovar..ListEdu.IdListEdu " +
                                   " LEFT JOIN CostsResult as cr on ReestrEdu.IdListEdu = cr.ExportIdListEdu" +
                                   " WHERE cr.IdCostsResultTask = " + IdCostsResultTask + " and slovar..ListEdu.LongName is not null " +
                                   " Group By cr.ExportIdListEdu, ReestrEdu.IdListEdu, slovar..ListEdu.Name, slovar..ListEdu.LongName  ORDER BY 1 ";
                var myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn);
                myCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                using (myReader)
                {
                    var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    table.Load(myReader);
                dt2 = table;
                }
                myReader.Dispose();
                cn.Close();

                b2 = true;
            }  
        }
        return dt2;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void OrgDatagrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Reports)(Application.OpenForms[0])).listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "1");  
        this.Close();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            ThirdForm = new Progress();
            ThirdForm.ShowDialog();
            e.Result = Loading(worker, e);
        }
        else
        {
            ThirdForm = new Progress();
            ThirdForm.ShowDialog();
            e.Result = Loading2(worker, e);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }            
        else
        {
            ThirdForm.Close();
            OrgDatagrid.DataSource = e.Result;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Код 3 формы (с таймером, прогрессбаром и кнопкой отмены асинхронной операции):

```
 public partial class Progress : Form
{


    public Progress()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Обрабатываем событие таймера.
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();

    }

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeLabel.Text = DateTimer.ToString("mm:ss");
        DateTimer = DateTimer.AddSeconds(1);
    }

    private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Organizations f = new Organizations();            
        if (f.backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            f.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
```

UPD: 
Решил проблему, перенеся вызов ThirdForm в метод checkBox1_CheckedChanged после вызова воркера. Беда была именно в вызове 3 формы из backgroundWorker1_DoWork. Внутри методов worker эти обращения работают некорректно (по крайней мере, не так, как хотелось бы). Однако осталась другая проблема - кнопка отмены операции в воркере с 3 формы не срабатывает (просто ничего не происходит). Пока не понимаю, как корректно вызвать завершение worker из другой формы.

UPD2: 
Проблема с кнопкой решена следующим образом:

Изменения в коде на 3 форме:

```
public event EventHandler Cancel = delegate { };

private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancel(sender, e);
        timer1.Stop();           
    }
```

Обработка во второй форме:

```
void CancelProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        if (checkflag)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            ThirdForm.Close();
            ThirdForm.timer1.Stop();
            ThirdForm.TimeLabel.Text = "";
            ThirdForm.DateTimer = new DateTime(0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        //backgroundWorker1.Dispose();            
        ThirdForm.Close();
        ThirdForm.timer1.Stop();
        ThirdForm.TimeLabel.Text = "";
        ThirdForm.DateTimer = new DateTime(0, 0);
        }
    }

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            checkflag = checkBox1.Checked;
            ThirdForm = new Progress();
            ThirdForm.timer1.Stop();
            ThirdForm.TimeLabel.Text = "";
            ThirdForm.Cancel += CancelProcess;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            ThirdForm.timer1.Start();
            ThirdForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Кстати, лучше обернуть `var cn = new SqlConnection()` в `using`, и убрать `myReader.Dispose()` (потому что `myReader` у вас уже обернут в `using`, который вызовет `Dispose()`, и убрать `cn.Close()` (потому что `using` на `cn` закроет соединение даже в случае исключения.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, поправлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Форма должна закрыться или вывестись сообщение об ошибке (либо MessageBox, либо программа упадет). Ошибка может не появиться, если возникла не в основном потоке (например, если backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted сработал в другом потоке).

предлагаю на всякий случай вставить Invoke внутрь этого метода

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
       if (e.Error != null)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
       }            
       else
       {
           ThirdForm.Close();
           OrgDatagrid.DataSource = e.Result;
           MessageBox.Show("Работа завершена");
       }
   ));
}
```

Заодно добавил лишний MessageBox, чтобы убедиться, что backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted вобще срабатывает.

Что касается прерывания BackgroundWorker с помощью метода Abort(), как для Thread, то, к сожалению, он его не поддерживает. Конечно же делать Abort() нежелательно, т.к. остается мертвый Connection. Хотя сборщик мусора его потом закроет.

Думаю есть смысл полностью отказаться от BackgroundWorker и все реализовать на Thread, помещая весь код работы с интерфейсом в Invoke() (формы нельзя менять в другом потоке).

Comment: Запустил с дополнительным MessageBox, заметил такую закономерность работы: Жмем на чекбокс - открывается 3 форма с прогрессбаром и таймером, висит бесконечно  - закрываем ее сами - проходит несколько секунд  - появляется 3 форма еще раз, опять закрываем - проходит то же время - датагрид обновляется и выводятся 2 MessageBox "Работа завершена", хмм.. Что может приводить к такому? Т.е. по идее, результат выдается, но во-первых, форма с таймером не закрывается, как нужно, только вручную, во-вторых, вызываемые формы дублируются.

Comment: Решил эту проблему, перенеся вызов ThirdForm в метод checkBox1_CheckedChanged после вызова воркера. Беда была именно в вызове 3 формы из backgroundWorker1_DoWork. Внутри методов worker эти обращения работают некорректно (по крайней мере, не так, как хотелось бы). Однако осталась другая проблема - кнопка отмены операции в воркере с 3 формы не срабатывает (просто ничего не происходит). Пока пытаюсь понять, почему. Добавил код 3 формы в пост с вопросом.

Comment: она не срабатывает, т.к. вызов CancelAsync() из основного потока всего лишь выставляется свойство CancelationPending, а вовсе не завершает выполнение DoWork(). Поэтому я и предложил отказаться от BackgroundWorker в пользу Thread, у которого есть замечательная функция Abort()